# Facebook album sharing & privacy question

Tags: privacy, facebook-photos

I posted an album on my profile that has custom settings/restricting people. I would like to share this album on my friends page, but one of our mutual friends I restricted. Can that restricted person see the shared album on her page? Will the settings I applied on my album still be in effect even though i shared it?

Example: I post an album on my page. I restrict John. John is a mutual friend of me & my friend Jen. I share this album on Jens page. Can John see the album being its now on her page?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the album page and make sure the privacy setting is set to custom.On custom settings add John to the field "Don't share with these people" or enter Jen on "share with these speicific people".

Now share the album on her page.That post will be visible only to her and you only.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Ok got it. I added "Johns" name to the "dont share with these people". Now, when I click on the "share album on friends timeline", that "custom" feature dissapears. Does that mean it's no longer in custom mode?

Comment: @db83 The privacy settings for your posts on your friends timeline also depends on the privacy settings made by your friend on his timeline.However, since you have restricted the John from viewing that photo, he will not be able to see the post even if the friends timeline privacy settings says public.